# bookdown: how to create a new blog entry?

Tags: r, blogdown

I've used the blogdown package to create my blog. It is already hosted in Netlify.

Now I need to create new entries for my blog.

I've created some but their are not recognized nor locally or externally.

For example in the blog folder I have a Rmd file that knits to HTML, but is not recognized in my web page::

```
content
    |_blog
      |_2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd
```

But when constructing manually the path for that page, I get a 404 error:

https://affectionate-allen-e5fa8f.netlify.com/blog/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.html

[image]

File in Github:

https://github.com/OmarGonD/omargonzalesdiaz/tree/master/content/blog

Github repository:

https://github.com/OmarGonD/omargonzalesdiaz

> Where should I place this Rmd file so when building website it's path
>   is recognized?

**Bonus:**

I cannot access the website, only the index is shown correctly, locally:

[image]

blog section locally:

[image]

Comment: blogdown parses the name to subdirectories. Check 2015/07/23/r-markdown

Comment: @Wil don't understand, could you provided the correct URL based on the hosted url of my blog?  https://affectionate-allen-e5fa8f.netlify.com

Comment: I’m not seeing your page where I expected it to be, but my comment was based on this line from the `config` file: `blog = "/blog/:year/:month/:day/:filename/"`

Comment: Is it this page? https://affectionate-allen-e5fa8f.netlify.com/blog/2015/07/23/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown/

Comment: Yes, ty. To make a link in me index.html's recent posts, I need to hardcode the url? or there is a way of automating it?

Comment: I believe the default is to show the most recent posts. Because your entry is 2015-07-23 it is not recent enough to make the list (the oldest post on the list is 2015-08-03). Try changing the date to 2015-09-01 and see if it appears on the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is at: https://affectionate-allen-e5fa8f.netlify.com/blog/2015/07/23/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown/. Most index pages will sort your posts in descending order, meaning the most recent ones will show up first. You post is dated 2015-07-23, which is too far in the past to be on the list of most recent posts that show up in the list on your `index.html` page.

You can edit the number of recent posts displayed. As the [theme documentation](https://github.com/devcows/hugo-universal-theme#recent-posts) states, the number of recents posts is set to 4. However, you can modify the `recent_posts.html` partial to change this. There is a line in https://github.com/OmarGonD/omargonzalesdiaz/blob/master/themes/hugo-universal-theme/layouts/partials/recent_posts.html that sets the range to the fist 4 posts. You can edit this to be any number you like. I set it to 5 and got this result.

[image: five recent posts]

Note that the 5th post is wrapped to the next line. If you wanted all 5 on the same line you would have to change the CSS so that the elements were small enough to fit on the same line.

This is a link to the exact line that you can change to set the number of recent posts: 
https://github.com/OmarGonD/omargonzalesdiaz/blob/cd84b9b8714cf38d60cc9171bcc6fc50bec67711/themes/hugo-universal-theme/layouts/partials/recent_posts.html#L20

Related to your URL, I would recommend reading about [permalinks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/configuration.html#options). The blogdown website explains the benefits of this method, but essentially it makes the links less brittle and less likely to break as you develop your website. This is a simple change; at a high level you would add a `slug` to your [metadata](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/content.html#yaml-metadata) and change your `config.toml` file "permalinks" section to:

```r
[permalinks]
    post = "/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"
```